# Is there a way to keep content of SVG file/xml hidden when embedded in a webpage?

Tags: html, xml, svg

Recently I had to create an SVG image to use within a webpage. Initially I did this with inline SVG XML within the HTML page, but then it occurred to me that it would be visible whenever anyone viewed the source of the page. As the image took a lot of work to create I wanted to protect it and so I added a watermark throughout the image so that if someone reused it my watermark would still be present. But in using XML inline, anyone with knowledge of SVG could just edit the SVG info to remove the watermark.

So I instead tried to create an image, then embed it as an object in the HTML. I did not realise that this would also make available the XML that is the content of the image to be freely available by inspecting the element when viewed in a browser. Thus I cannot even add a watermark to my image to protect it.

So I am wondering is there anyway to hide the internals of the SVG file from people viewing the page, or is my only option to create a raster image with watermark present and embed that in my page also? Clearly this is a horrible option, so I am wondering I can hide my SVG details in some manner??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SVG and HTML are open web technologies and that's one of the reasons some people prefer them over Flash or Silverlight or any of a number of other technologies that can make it harder to determine how things work.

You have copyright over everything you produce though so if you put a copyright notice in and you find that copies appear elsewhere then you have recourse under copyright law.

Answer (score 2):

It could still be decoded, but you could always make it a data URI.  A user wouldn't be able to see your code just by viewing the source at least.  You can read a little bit about that [here](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#:%7E:text=%20data%20uri.)

Comment: Thanks for that - the resource you linked to is very helpful to me.

Comment: Do note that there are some disadvantages with this approach, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Disadvantages, and that it's trivial to view and save the svg content using the web developer tools built into the browsers even if you take this route.

Comment: @ErikDahlström So it seems then that the overall answer to my question is simply "No" ?

Comment: @mathematician1975 it is certainly possible to make it harder or less desirable to reuse/"steal" the content, at the expense of readability and/or content efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your SVG your identification, make it either transparent, tiny that won't be seen or under an other element. This won't stop others using you file but you have evidence that you made it, in case you have to prove that.